# Let me understand the model

Tags: r, lstm, lstm-stateful

I am dealing with a problem to predict electrical power output using LSTM in R. I found a very suitable code for my data [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/11/lstm-with-keras-tensorflow/). But the problem is I do not understand what is meant by

1. Units
2. Input_shape
3. layer_dropout
4. layer_dropout
5. loss
6. adam

below is the code from where I have mentioned list of my question.

```
    model %>%
  layer_lstm(units = 100,
             input_shape = c(datalags, 2),
             batch_size = batch.size,
             return_sequences = TRUE,
             stateful = TRUE) %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>%
  layer_lstm(units = 50,
             return_sequences = FALSE,
             stateful = TRUE) %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1)

model %>%
  compile(loss = 'mae', optimizer = 'adam')
```

Answer (score 0):

These arguments are defined in the reference documentation here:

https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/layer_lstm.html

> Arguments object   Model or layer object
>
> units  Positive integer, dimensionality of the output space.
>
> activation     Activation function to use. Default: hyperbolic tangent
> (tanh). If you pass NULL, no activation is applied (ie. "linear"
> activation: a(x) = x).
>
> recurrent_activation   Activation function to use for the recurrent
> step.
>
> use_bias   Boolean, whether the layer uses a bias vector.
>
> return_sequences   Boolean. Whether to return the last output in the
> output sequence, or the full sequence.
>
> return_state   Boolean (default FALSE). Whether to return the last
> state in addition to the output.
>
> go_backwards   Boolean (default FALSE). If TRUE, process the input
> sequence backwards and return the reversed sequence.
>
> stateful   Boolean (default FALSE). If TRUE, the last state for each
> sample at index i in a batch will be used as initial state for the
> sample of index i in the following batch.
>
> unroll     Boolean (default FALSE). If TRUE, the network will be
> unrolled, else a symbolic loop will be used. Unrolling can speed-up a
> RNN, although it tends to be more memory-intensive. Unrolling is only
> suitable for short sequences.
>
> kernel_initializer     Initializer for the kernel weights matrix, used
> for the linear transformation of the inputs.
>
> recurrent_initializer  Initializer for the recurrent_kernel weights
> matrix, used for the linear transformation of the recurrent state.
>
> bias_initializer   Initializer for the bias vector.
>
> unit_forget_bias   Boolean. If TRUE, add 1 to the bias of the forget
> gate at initialization. Setting it to true will also force
> bias_initializer="zeros". This is recommended in Jozefowicz et al.
>
> kernel_regularizer     Regularizer function applied to the kernel weights
> matrix.
>
> recurrent_regularizer  Regularizer function applied to the
> recurrent_kernel weights matrix.
>
> bias_regularizer   Regularizer function applied to the bias vector.
>
> activity_regularizer   Regularizer function applied to the output of
> the layer (its "activation")..
>
> kernel_constraint  Constraint function applied to the kernel weights
> matrix.
>
> recurrent_constraint   Constraint function applied to the
> recurrent_kernel weights matrix.
>
> bias_constraint    Constraint function applied to the bias vector.
>
> dropout    Float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the units to drop for the
> linear transformation of the inputs.
>
> recurrent_dropout  Float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the units to
> drop for the linear transformation of the recurrent state.
>
> input_shape    Dimensionality of the input (integer) not including the
> samples axis. This argument is required when using this layer as the
> first layer in a model.
>
> batch_input_shape  Shapes, including the batch size. For instance,
> batch_input_shape=c(10, 32) indicates that the expected input will be
> batches of 10 32-dimensional vectors. batch_input_shape=list(NULL, 32)
> indicates batches of an arbitrary number of 32-dimensional vectors.
>
> batch_size     Fixed batch size for layer
>
> dtype  The data type expected by the input, as a string (float32,
> float64, int32...)
>
> name   An optional name string for the layer. Should be unique in a
> model (do not reuse the same name twice). It will be autogenerated if
> it isn't provided.
>
> trainable  Whether the layer weights will be updated during training.
>
> weights    Initial weights for layer.